# How to access the anchor tag's HTML

Tags: jquery

```
<td class="ms-gb">
  <a>
    <span class="ms-commentexpand-iconouter">
      <img class="ms-commentexpand-icon">
    </span> 
    Mutual Funds 
    <img class="right-arrow">
  </a> : Mutual Funds <span>(3)</span>
</td>
```

How can I get the anchor tag's HTML?

Comment: Add more specifics pls. If you just like to access all anchor tags you can use $('a').each(function(){var anchorTag = $(this);});

Comment: You can use `$('.ms-gb').find('a').html()`

Comment: @Akshay, why use two methods? why not use combinators?

Comment: You can use both. I dont find chaining syntax convenient  thats why I used two methods

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 4):

Use [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
console.log($('a').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="ms-gb">
  <a>
    <span class="ms-commentexpand-iconouter">
<img class="ms-commentexpand-icon"></span> Mutual Funds
    <img class="right-arrow">
  </a>: Mutual Funds <span>(3)</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the following line to get the html of `a`

```
var tempHtml = $('td.ms-gb > a').wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

after unrap the `a` by following line

```
$('td.ms-gb > a').unwrap('<div>');
```

Comment: how about `$('td.ms-gb > a')[0].outerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

use this to get all html contents

```
$(".ms-gb a").html()
```

use this to get text of elements inside

```
$(".ms-gb a").text()
```

use this to get children in javascript object format

```
$(".ms-gb a").children()
```